# How to get the actual output file name from maven

Tags: maven, ant

I try to configure the maven ant plugin to copy the built artifact to a custom location:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>

            <copy verbose="true" 
              file="target/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}"
              tofile="${user.home}/tmp/test/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}"/>

          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This works fine, as long as the packaging is one of the standard ones... but if the packaging of the project is "bundle" (which generates a .jar), then the ${project.packaging} variable is "bundle" and the actual file ends with ".jar" = the copy fails.

How can I get the "real" name of the file that is put into the output directory?

Comment: What does the bundle packaging achieve? I can't find any reference to it on google.

Comment: The packaging bundle is used with the maven-bundle-plugin to create jar files (osgi-bundles) that can be deployed in an osgi container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that reliably. For example, a POM can have several artifacts as result (binary JAR, sources JAR, test binary JAR, test sources JAR). Which one of them is the correct one to copy?

Possible solutions:

1. Replace `${project.packaging}` with `jar`. Should work in most cases.
2. Use a file set instead of a hard coded file name to let Ant figure out the names based on patterns.

Answer (score 11):

In ant build.xml using:

```
${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a property called `packaging-suffix` or something similair. In all your projects (or in the super pom if you have one) you can define this property to have the value `${project.packaging}` but in the bundle projects your define the value as `jar`. You then reference the property in your antrun plugin congfiguration.

Depending on how your project(s) are set up, this may or may not be a good solution.

I.e:

```
<properties>
  <packaging-suffix>${project.packaging}</packaging-suffix>
</properties>
```

vs

```
<properties>
  <packaging-suffix>jar</packaging-suffix>
</properties>
```

then

```
<copy verbose="true"  
  file="target/${project.build.finalName}.${packaging-suffix}"
  tofile="${user.home}/tmp/test/${project.build.finalName}.${packaging-suffix}"/>
```